# Is there a list of reference for Django Rest Framework Errors in serializer validation?

Tags: python, django, error-handling, django-rest-framework

I am trying to handle all errors in my application before they occur, the validation errors appears through

```
serializer.is_valid()
serializer.errors
```

I am going through [rest framework serializer code base](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py) right now to find all errors, but I feel its a bit inefficient, are there any references for common errors in serializer validation?

Comment: If you are working with a serializer based on a model, you will get errors based on the model's field, such us required field and datatypes. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of Serializer Validation in Django REST Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591574/order-of-serializer-validation-in-django-rest-framework)