# ModelSerializer field validation for empty string

Tags: json, django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm having a problem with django rest framework.
My front is posting data to drf, and one of the fields could be `null` or an empty string `""`.

```
# models.py
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publication_time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)


# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Book

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'publication_time')
```

`publication_time` could either be `blank` or `""`.

The blank case works, in fact when I post a json `{"title": "yeah a book", "publication_time": none}` everything is fine.

When I send `{"title": "yeah a book", "publication_time":""}` I do get a validation error `"Time has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: hh:mm[:ss[.uuuuuu]]."`

I've tried to add a field validator to the serializer class:

```
def validate_publication_time(self, value):
    if not value:
        return None
```

Or even using the extra_kwargs

```
# ....
def empty_string_to_none(value):
    if not value:
        return None    

# ....
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'publication_time')
        extra_kwargs = {'publication_time': {'validators' : [empty_string_to_none]} }
```

What I am trying to do is to transform an empty string to None (that should be accepted by the serializer and the model) before any validation occurs or as the first validation rule.

**PROBLEM:**
The problem is that the `validate_publication_time` is never called and I get a validation error before even hitting the function. As I've [understood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27591842/1191416) there is a specific order in which the validators run, but now I have no idea how to solve my issue.

**QUESTION:**
What I want to do is to actually clean the data in order to transform `""` into `None` before any validation is run. Is it possible? How?

**EDIT:**
This is the representation of my serializer:

```
# from myapp.serializers import BookSerializer
# serializer = BookSerializer()
# print repr(serializer)
# This is the print result:
BookSerializer():
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    title = CharField(max_length=100)
    publication_time = TimeField(allow_null=True, required=False)
```

So as you can see the publication_time field could be null, isn't it?

Comment: Did you ever find a good answer to this question?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and finally found a solution.

In order to deal with `''` before the error occurs, you need to override the `to_internal_value` method:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if data.get('publication_time', None) == '':
            data.pop('publication_time')
        return super(BookSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I would only make the following editions: turn the if statement to `if 'publication_time' in data and data['publication_time'] == ''` and set `data['publication_time'] = None` if it passes. As the author wants to convert an empty string to None, I think this way it would be more precise.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried to [override serialization behavior](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior)? What you need is override `.to_internal_value(self, data)`

Answer (score 4):

the `kwarg` is `allow_null` and `allow_blank` not `null` and `blank`.

Comment: I don't think so, those are django model fields, not serializer fields

Comment: I've edited the question so you see also the serializer instance representation

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer. This worked for me.

Comment: @Leonardo What he means is that when you declare the variable in meta data in serializer you can say sometext= serializers.CharField(allow_blank=True) not in model,py but in serializer py . This would overwrite the default behavior as well. 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/

Answer (score 1):

You can override serializer's `save` method where you would check if the value is an empty string and if it is then set it to Null.

In your serializer (untested):

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs)
    if self.publication_time == "":
        self.publication_time = Null
    super.save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or, you can do like that in a view(this is how I do that):

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    publication_time = self.kwargs['publication_time']
    if publication_time == "":
        publication_time = Null
    serializer.save(publication_time=publication_time)
```

only then you'll also need to overwrite perform_create if you also need this when you POST, not only when PUT

Answer (score 0):

Answer of @Ivan Blinov is correct, except you should allow the **data** to be mutable, otherwise you get this error:

```
 AttributeError: This QueryDict instance is immutable
```

so the complete answer is:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if data.get('publication_time', None) == '':
            data._mutable = True
            data.pop('publication_time')
    return super(BookSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
```