# Django rest framework datetimefield won't validate empty string

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've developed a web hook to receive transactions from my bank. I use Django-rest-framework to validate the data before saving it to my database. However my bank passes a blank string for the field 'settled' and Django-rest-framework doesn't seem to be able to validate a form with blank values in a datetime field. null is ok, but an empty string is not. What to do?

JSON passed by my bank:

```
{
    "type": "transaction.created",
    "data": {
        "account_id": "acc_00008gju41AHyfLUzBUk8A",
        "amount": -350,
        "created": "2015-09-04T14:28:40Z",
        "currency": "GBP",
        "description": "Ozone Coffee Roasters",
        "id": "tx_00008zjky19HyFLAzlUk7t",
        "category": "eating_out",
        "is_load": false,
        "settled": "",
        "merchant": {
            "address": {
                "address": "98 Southgate Road",
                "city": "London",
                "country": "GB",
                "latitude": 51.54151,
                "longitude": -0.08482400000002599,
                "postcode": "N1 3JD",
                "region": "Greater London"
            },
            "created": "2015-08-22T12:20:18Z",
            "group_id": "grp_00008zIcpbBOaAr7TTP3sv",
            "id": "merch_00008zIcpbAKe8shBxXUtl",
            "logo": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/527043602623389696/68_SgUWJ.jpeg",
            "emoji": "",
            "name": "The De Beauvoir Deli Co.",
            "category": "eating_out"
        }
    }
}
```

```
class MerchantSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    logo = serializers.URLField(max_length=250, required=False)

class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    account_id = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    amount = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
    currency = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=3)
    description = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=250)
    id = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    category = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
    is_load = serializers.BooleanField()
    settled = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    merchant = MerchantSerializer()

class TransactionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    type = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    data = DataSerializer()
```

Comment: Try allow_blank=True

Comment: allow_blank is not a valid keyword argument for datetime fields

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `to_internal_value`:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if data.get('settled') == '':
            data['settled'] = None
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but I get: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'get_internal_value'

Comment: It'd be great if we didn't have to hack DRF to get it to do perfectly reasonable things that any normal person would expect it to do out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

I think It would be done by trying this
`settled = serializers.DateTimeField(required=False, allow_null=True , blank = True)`

Comment: I guess your problem can solve by overriding to_internal_value.have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37124344/modelserializer-field-validation-for-empty-string

Comment: `serializers.DateTimeField` does not allow `blank` parameter.