# Error: too many values to unpack (expected 2) when raise error with serializers.ValidationError

Tags: python, django, validation, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to validate empty fields in an endpoint by overwriting `to_internal_value` function and displaying an error message with [ValidationError](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators), very similar as the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46071064/6796652):

serializer.py

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    missing = []
    for k in ['comments']:
        try:
            if data[k] == '':
                missing.append(k)
        except Exception as e:
            missing.append(k)
        if len(missing):
            raise serializers.ValidationError("The following fields are required: %s" % ','.join(missing))
    return data
```

The problem is that I get: `Error: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` when `raise serializers.ValidationError` instruction is executed and `data` is comming with comments field empty (''):

```
(Pdb) data
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['<csrfmiddlewaretoken>'], 'comments': [''], 'user': ['']}>
```

Even testing with a simple string:

`raise serializers.ValidationError("The following fields are required: comments")`

I receive the same error. In the python console, raise throw the error:

```
>>> from rest_framework.serializers import ValidationError
>>> from rest_framework import serializers
>>> data={'comments': [''], 'user': ['']}
>>> missing=[]
>>> missing.append('comments')
>>> raise serializers.ValidationError("The following fields are required: %s" % ','.join(missing))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: [ErrorDetail(string='The following fields are required: comments', code='invalid')]
```

Instead of `serializers.ValidationError()` I had to use `ValueError()` and It works good, but I guess that it's not the suggested way.

**Edit**
I was using:

```
Django==2.2.4
djangorestframework==3.10.3
```

Then I upgraded to:

```
Django==2.2.9
djangorestframework==3.11.0
```

With the same results.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error (too many values to unpack). Raiseerror returns only  `ValidationError: [ErrorDetail(string='The following fields are required:  ', code='invalid')]` django 3.0.1, djangoframework 3.11.0

Comment: I upgraded to ```djangorestframework==3.11.0``` but I received the same error. I updated my question adding the dict (data) that I receive from the DRF Api view

Answer (score 7):

The reason this happens is that `to_internal_value` collects all the validation errors and passes them up as a dictionary, so that the resulting `400` response can include all the errors that were found rather than just the first one it hits. This should work:

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    missing = []
    for k in ['comments']:
        try:
            if data[k] == '':
                missing.append(k)
        except Exception as e:
            missing.append(k)
        if len(missing):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"The following fields are required": missing}
            )
    return data
```

That said, if all you're doing is validating that something is present, I'd suggest declaring `required=True` on the field in your serializer instead, and then DRF will do this check for you.

Comment: I tried with your answer but unfortunately I got the same result. I can't use just ```required=True``` because that validation does not force you to send the field if it is optional. At the end, I think that according with your answer, drf validators documentation needs an updated related with that error.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that `ValidationError` raised inside `run_validation` should be created with dict, for example:

```
ValidationError(','.join(missing): "These field are required")
```

Comment: This answer is absolutely correct. After fixing the data type going into ValidationError(dict) my issue was solved.

Comment: i think you're missing the {} here